# I connect the half spheres what am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am the bridge between two half spheres , don't think about worm hole.
>
> I am the largest white matter there , don't think about Dark matter.
>
> If you are able to read this puzzle then will have it , don't think about seeing yours ,you will die..

what am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is is the:

> [Corpus callosum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_callosum)?

*I am the bridge between two half spheres , don't think about worm hole.*

> It connects the two hemispheres of the brain

*I am the largest white matter there , don't think about black matter.*

> It is the largest white matter structure in the brain

*If you are able to read this puzzle then will have it , don't think about seeing yours ,you will die..*

> You need a brain to solve a puzzle, but if your brain is exposed you probably won't be alive anymore

Comment: Sometimes they [sever it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_callosotomy) (for good reasons) and they find some really [interesting things](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfYbgdo8e-8) about how the two halves work together and also completely independently.